# Check if a document contains 2 strings

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore with Android (Kotlin). In one of my collections if want to check if there exists a document that contains 2 user ids. I want to write to my collection if there does not exist such a document. Otherwise, I want to get the id of that document. Here's what my documents look like:

[image: document]

Given 2 strings how do I check if a document contains both of them?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And instead of describing how your database looks like, please add a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a specific document contains those two particular ids, you need to use a `Query`. I assume that the document from the screenshot exists in a collection named "users", please use the following lines of code:

```
var rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
var usersRef = rootRef.collection("users")
var queryByTWoIds = usersRef.whereEqualTo("p1", "9EBt ... LX62").whereEqualTo("p2", "Tsh6 ... Fin1")
queryByTWoIds!!.get().addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
    for (document in documents) {
        Log.d(TAG, "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
    }
}.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
    Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", exception)
}
```

Please note that in Cloud Firestore is permitted to chain multiple `whereEqualTo()` method calls.

Comment: Oh thanks! But what happens If one whereEqualTo is true but second one is not? I'm running this code and the query is succesfull twice while i only have 1 document in my collection right now, why?

Comment: Data already exits: [DocumentSnapshot{key=conversations/5lD92VBw408ncMav8zdB, metadata=SnapshotMetadata{hasPendingWrites=false, isFromCache=false}, doc=Document{key=conversations/5lD92VBw408ncMav8zdB, data=ArraySortedMap{(initialTimestamp=>1584887186159), (messages=>[]), (p1=>9EBtkkA1GedhROaNaSUzyyc2LX62), (p1Name=>Amol Borkar),.....]
2020-03-22 20:53:40.610 15949-15949/com.halalrishtey D/HomeFragment: Data already exits: []

Comment: *"If one whereEqualTo is true but second one is not"* then you'll get no result. Chaining two `whereEqualTo()` methods is an `AND` operation and **not** an `OR`. I don't understand what does *"is successful twice"* mean. Using the above query on a database that looks exactly like in your screenshot, a single document should be returned.